# Sending parameters as path segments doesn't work in ServiceStack

Tags: c#, get, servicestack

I'm trying to make a GET request to my SS service but the parameters have empty values when I send them as URL segments. According to https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Routing I can call the service in two ways:

/resource/p1/p2/p3
or
/resource?p1=v1&p2=v2&p3=v3

The first method never works (the parameters have default values depending on their types) and the second one always works. I wan't to call the service using the first method.

Here's my code

```
//Request DTO    
[Route("/test/{Param1}/{Param2}/{Param3}")]
public class Test
{
    public string Param1 { get; set; }
    public int Param2 { get; set; }
    public string Param3 { get; set; }
}

//Response DTO    
public class TestResponse : IHasResponseStatus
{
    public ResponseStatus ResponseStatus { get; set; }
    public string Inputs { get; set; }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your question is already answered here: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14128684/servicestack-routes-and-parameters?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out but from what I can see my DTOs are the same as what mythz recommended. Why is it not working though?

Comment: It will work. I just created a scriptcs example and tested with "/Test/param1/2/param3" and it worked fine. What are exact url are you testing with? Is there more code you can post? Your resource example uses all strings but your Test DTO is string/int/string

Comment: It seems that it does work in general. However, in my case the value of {Param1} is a Url. For example, it doesn't accept **http%3A%2F%2Fdev%2Fasdf.png**. Calling the service using a browser or Postman throws a 400 bad request error. Curiously, the same encoded value works just fine if I remove the encoded "http://" part. Does anybody know what might be causing this strange behavior?

Comment: I've also noticed that when sending a string value with an encoded slash (%2F) as a path segment in a ServiceStack request, it will fail to properly bind or route the request.

Comment: I found [this discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13691829/795339) that seems to confirm that this is a general limitation of ServiceStack, at least when running on IIS.

Comment: @esker Alright, now it makes sense. Thanks for bringing closure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to close the question: esker posted a link where mythz confirms that what we're experiencing is actually an IIS/ASP.NET bug.